# Inter annotator agreement (or disagreement) for highly imbalance annotations?

Tags: python, unbalanced-classes, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have a time-series dataset which is annotated by 4 individual annotators where I have following things in annotations.

1. Its possible that one annotator has not annotated all samples (i.e. missing annotations).
2. It has multiple classes and one sample can have one or more classes (i.e. multi-label).

I can handle point2 by analyzing each class individually.

My main concern is my data is highly **imbalanced** i.e. `label 0` and `label 1` in data might be 95% and 5% (this is just an example and ratio is unknown but definitely very high for `0s`) hence agreement probability may be high because of agreement in `0s`. What measure might be more reliable here which takes disagreement in account?

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the issue of missing annotations using a generalized agreement coefficient (see Gwet, 2014). This will basically use all the data you do have. You can handle the issue of multi-label annotations as you suggested, by treating the classes individually. For the imbalanced classes, you have several options. One would be to use a chance-adjusted agreement measure that is sensitive to class distributions (e.g., Cohen's kappa or Scott's pi), although in all likelihood you would just end up with a low score due to the high expected chance agreement (Feinstein & Cicchetti, 1990). Another would be to use category-specific agreement (i.e., positive agreement and negative agreement for binary classes) as described by Cicchetti & Feinstein (1990). Then you look to see how good your agreement is on the positive and negative classes separately; you don't get a single number like accuracy or kappa but you get around the distributional difficulties.

Gwet, K. L. (2014). Handbook of inter-rater reliability: The definitive guide to measuring the extent of agreement among raters (4th ed.). Advanced Analytics.

Feinstein, A. R., & Cicchetti, D. V. (1990). High agreement but low kappa: I. The problems of two paradoxes. *Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 43*(6), 543–549. https://doi.org/10/fwqv5m

Cicchetti, D. V., & Feinstein, A. R. (1990). High agreement but low kappa: II. Resolving the paradoxes. *Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 43*(6), 551–558. https://doi.org/10/czkxkb